# Getting Div to float to bottom of parent div?

Tags: css

Hi I have a simple sidebar inside a div which has height:100% and I need the sidebar to float as high as the container becomes. Since I have a content div, and the content div will change on each page, it's inside this parent div which ideally should change in height and thus the sidebar would run the entire height of this parent div.

http://mibsoftware.us/clients/weber/?page_id=2

However in the above link I'm unable to get that to work. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

[Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Comment: great that seemed to work - almost. i have the same exact coding as he states yet the sidebar isn't stretching to the bottom of the parent div (http://mibsoftware.us/clients/weber/?page_id=2).

Answer (score 0):

Get it to float BELOW the bottom of that div (possibly in a simillar div), and then set it's `position` to `relative` and `top: -height_of_div px`.